# Xamarin.forms AppLinks.RegisterLink() method fails when built in "Release" mode only

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, applinks

I had implemented Xamarin.forms AppLinks functionality into my app. It works fine, but only when running in Debug mode. I had reported this issue [here](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=59917). The logcat shows the following exception:

`I/MonoDroid(24606): UNHANDLED EXCEPTION:
I/MonoDroid(24606): Java.Lang.LinkageError: no non-static method "Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzkk;.start(Lcom/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient;Lcom/google/android/gms/appindexing/Action;)Lcom/google/android/gms/common/api/PendingResult;"`

I am trying to figure this problem out for the past 3 weeks. Any help is greatly appreciated at this point. Thank you

Comment: Check whether you have included all the dll's. Even i faced the same problem. By including all the dll's it worked fine in release mode.

Comment: How do I check this? I use Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

If you look under the solution explorer on the left, you can right click on References and select Edit References select .Net Assemblies and pick the dll to add to the project. When it is added the first time it will be in the references for future projects.

I went through and added my normal dlls even if not needed in the current project to get them in the reference list. My app was working fine in debug mode but didn't work when released, after this it worked fine.

Comment: I don't know which dll(s) to add -- the exception occurs within Xamarin own function.

Comment: update or add all the dll(s) related to googleapiclient/googleservices

Comment: They are all included already, there are 4 of them. Thank you, Rakesh for your patience with me.

Comment: Final thing. Just try including all the dll's available in xamarin whether you use it or not.

Comment: There are too many dll's there.  Is there a way to identify one or more required dlls?